# How to execute a case expression when it is embedded in a cell?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table where field2 sometimes consists of data and sometimes consists of CASE Expressions embedded in the cell. I'd like field3 to equal field2 when field2 has data, but I'd like field3 to return the result of the Case Expression when the Case Expression is embedded in field2, like this:

```
field1        field2        field3
A             Data          Data
A             Data          Data
B             Data          Data
B             Case Exp..    Result of Case Exp
B             Data          Data
```

Here's my current method:

```
Declare @field2variable as NVARCHAR(max);
Select @field2variable=t.field2 From table;

Select 
     t.field1, 
     t.field2,
     Case When t.field2 NOT Like '%Data%' Then EXECUTE SP_EXECUTESQL @field2variable
     Else t.field2
     End As field3
Into new_table
From table t
```

- The first problem is that I'm trying to assign @field2variable to an entire column instead of a single value.
- The second problem is that it SQL won't let me run "EXECUTE SP_EXECUTESQL" in the select statement.

Comment: You can only do this with dynamic sql.

Comment: You really need to consider your design here. Storing sql in a column is not a good way to handle this. As mentioned you have to use dynamic sql here but the best approach would be redesigning your data so this isn't needed.

Answer (score 0):

if you need to have that table you should create that like this :

```
Declare @field2variable as NVARCHAR(max);
declare @coun int;
select  @coun=count(id) from table;
declare @idd  int =0;
declare @bb nvarchar(50);
while @coun>0
begin
set @idd=(select id from ( select id,ROW_NUMBER() over(order by id) as rowss from table )as a where rowss=@coun)
set @bb=cast(( select field2 from table where id=@idd)as nvarchar(50))
if(left(@bb,1)<>'D')
exec SP_EXECUTESQL @bb
set @coun=@coun-1;
--insert into table ......
end
```

at the end you should create your table and insert the result of this into that table

Comment: on if statement u can do better and check the case one